# How to find out whether two "Events" overlap using "Start" and "End" datetime objects. Python

Tags: python, datetime, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google calendar API with Python, in order to compile events on a given day, to see how much time I spend on certain events per day/week etc.

I was originally just subtracting the `End` time from the `Start` time to achieve a `Duration`, and then adding all event `Duration` on a given day.

The thing is, sometimes I overlap events, for example Lunch and Reading might overlap and then cause the program to believe I've magically spent an extra 30 minutes in a day.

The google API gives (as can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events)) the following values amongst others:

```
  "start": {
    "date": date,
    "dateTime": datetime,
    "timeZone": string
  },
  "end": {
    "date": date,
    "dateTime": datetime,
    "timeZone": string
```

So if I have a long list of `Event` objects, that all have a `Start` and `End` time, what would be a good way of checking that there are Event overlaps?

Comment: Have you had a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap?rq=1

Comment: Great link, thanks! Didn't come up through my searches. I'll take a long look now.

Comment: In that case I guess I could also pose this question: How would you check a list of events with Start and End datetimes. Would you have to check every event against each other, or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "check a list of events with Start and End datetimes". Now that the main question you asked is no longer relevant it would be better to update it to mention what exactly it is you want to do so that you get an answer

Comment: @k4kuz0: somewhat related: [Python - Removing overlapping lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16314541/4279)