# How to correctly merge overlapping datetime ranges in Python

Tags: python, list, datetime, merge, tuples

I'm trying to merge overlapping datetime ranges. I have list of datetime ranges as tuples in a list:

```
data = [(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 16, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 22, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 23, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 0, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 2, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 3, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 16, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 14, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 20, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 21, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 22, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 2, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 3, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 16, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 14, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 19, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 20, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 22, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 2, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 3, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 16, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 14, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 20, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 21, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 21, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 22, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 22, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 2, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 3, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 16, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 14, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 22, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 23, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 2, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 3, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 16, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 14, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 20, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 22, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 22, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 16, 2, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 16, 3, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 16, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 16, 16, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 17, 2, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 17, 3, 30))]
```

Here's my current code:

```
import datetime

def merge_date_ranges(data):

    result = []

    for t1, t2 in ((data[i], data[i+1]) for i in range(len(data)-1)):   
        if t1[1] >= t2[0]:
            result.append((min(t1[0], t2[0]), max(t1[1], t2[1])))
        else:
            result.append(t1)
```

If T1 (first datetime range) and T2 (second datetime range) do NOT overlap then I just add T1 to the new list (result). If T1 and T2 DO overlap, then I add the merged tuple to the new list (result).

My problem is what happens after a merge. For example:

```
T1 = (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 16, 0))
T2 = (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 0))
```

T1 and T2 are merged and the following is added to my new list:

```
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 16, 0))
```

So now I want my code (in the next iteration of the for loop) to compare the merged tuple (new T1) with the next datetime range in my list:

```
T1 = (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 16, 0))
T2 = (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 22, 0))
```

But instead, here's what T1 and T2 look like:

```
T1 = (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 0))
T2 = (datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 22, 0))
```

And T1 gets added to my new list (which I don't want) because it was already merged previously.

But I just can't get my head around how to do this. It would be easier if I was able to update my original list by replacing T2 with the merged tuple and deleting T1. But as I understand this is not possible or even a good practice.

After a week of pulling my hair out, I'm posting my first question here in the hope that someone can help me get my sanity back. :)

**Update**
Basically I want to end up with a new list where no datetime ranges overlap.

Comment: related: [Python - Removing overlapping lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16312871/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.
Give it a test and comment:

```
def merge_date_ranges(data):
    result = []
    t_old = data[0]
    for t in data[1:]:
        if t_old[1] >= t[0]:  #I assume that the data is sorted already
            t_old = ((min(t_old[0], t[0]), max(t_old[1], t[1])))
        else:
            result.append(t_old)
            t_old = t
    else:
        result.append(t_old)
    return result
```

I am assuming that the dates are already sorted.

BTW, I see that the only weird dates are thos that are single days, maybe you should fix your input data instead.

```
salida = merge_date_ranges(data)
for item in [t for t in data if t not in salida]:
    print item

(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 14, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 14, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 14, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 22, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 14, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 22, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 14, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 22, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. You're a star!

Comment: Thanks. I actually added those dates to the list  to set start and end times for each day. The next step for me will be to exclude any datetime ranges outside of that range. For example if my start time is (14, 0) and end time is (22,0) for a given day, then I would exclude (9,0) to (10,0) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: given the new information, you should still do a loop, but base it on a boolean value and check for overlaps.

```
import datetime

def merge_date_ranges(data):

    input = data
    result = []
    overlap = True # we assume there's overlap to begin with

    while(overlap):
        overlap = False # will remain false unless overlap is found

        for t1, t2 in ((input[i], input[i+1]) for i in range(len(input)-1)):   
            if t1[1] >= t2[0]:
                overlap = True # an overlap was found, so loop will continue
                result.append((min(t1[0], t2[0]), max(t1[1], t2[1])))
            else:
                result.append(t1)

        if(overlap):
            input = result # preparing the next round

    return result
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. I'm sorry if i wasn't clearer. Basically what I want is to end up with a new list where no datetime ranges overlap.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect the new information, does this make more sense for what you need?