# Checking two time intervals are overlapping or not

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time, compare

I have this kind of two different intervals sets:

```
Intervals1:
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.276504', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:39.286168'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.722193', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.301116'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.329731', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.812676'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.146669', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.419473'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.413005', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.203540'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.686456', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.442964'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:43.198191', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.746994'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:44.502593', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:43.288611'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:46.525823', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:44.709627'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:47.098280', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:46.886541'}
--------------------------
Interval2:
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.482954', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:39.590220'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.615738', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.649375'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:46.365902', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:45.987907'}
{'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:47.698375', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:46.510641'}
```

I'm converting these datetime strings to real datetime objects with this line:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(dictionary['starting_time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

What I'm trying to do here is to matching overlapping time intervals by comparing these two different sets.

For example; Intervals1[0] and Intervals2[0] is overlapping
but Intervals1[7] and Intervals2[0] is not overlapping.

So what is the correct way to do this? A brief explanation would be enough for me.

Comment: it seems irrelevant that the values are string representing a date/time. The question would have remained the same if you'd used lists with tuples: `L1 = [(1, 10), (100, 120)]`, `L2 = [(9, 15), (50, 60)]` -- here `L1[0]` and `L2[0]` overlap. Related: [Merging Overlapping Intervals](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/69242/6143) and [Python - Removing overlapping lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16312871/4279).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime` objects support comparisons, so you just need to check if the first start time is between the start and end of the other, or if the first end time is between the start stop of other or vice versa.

```
def overlap(first_inter,second_inter):
    for f,s in ((first_inter,second_inter), (second_inter,first_inter)):
        #will check both ways
        for time in (f["starting_time"], f["ending_time"]):
            if s["starting_time"] < time < s["ending_time"]:
                return True
    else:
        return False
```

Edit: also note that because the format of your date string has the most significant values first it would just as easily compare without making them into `datetime` objects.

Edit2:  Here is a recipe to record all combinations and their results into a dictionary:

```
import itertools

combos = {(i1,i2):overlap(int1,int2)
             for (i1,int1),(i2,int2)
                in itertools.product(enumerate(Intervals1),enumerate(Intervals2))}

print(*combos.items(),sep="\n")
```

this way `combos[0,1]` will be wither `Intervals[0]` and `Intervals[1]` overlapped and so on.

Then to just get a set of overlapping times you can use:

```
overlapped = set(com for com,was_overlapped in combos.items() if was_overlapped)
```

LAST EDIT: I apologize for using really long [`dict` comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), it is very difficult to work with data in confusing format, if the original list of times has a pattern to it then just using the for loop portion of the dict comprehension would yield desired result:

```
for (i1,int1),(i2,int2) in itertools.product(enumerate(Intervals1),enumerate(Intervals2)):
    if overlap(int1,int2):
        print(i1,i2)
```

or to sort the `overlapped` set you can use the `sorted` builtin:

```
overlapped = sorted(overlapped) #this gives a list
```

Comment: Thx, It's working for one by one comparison, but I need to check more combinations if it returns False. For example, Intervals1[0] and Intervals2[0] is not overlapping but Invervals1[0] and Intervals2[1] could be overlapping. So how can I compare whole lists with minimum time complexity?

Comment: By the way these Intervals1 and Intervals2 lists have a time order in itself.

Comment: I didn't notice the order in the lists themselves, in that case there is probably a faster way then the one I just added, but it was able to do 10000 runs with `timeit.timeit` in 6.9 seconds so it is probably sufficient

Comment: How can I get only True ones from combos and also what is `timeit.timeit` could you explain a little bit :)

Comment: added edit for getting set of only True ones but for `timeit` you should go to https://www.google.com/#q=python+timeit  or https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit, my code was `def test():combos = <code in answer>;  print(timeit.timeit(test,number=100000))`

Comment: OK one last question. In combos we have lost time order. How can I sort combos by index number to protect time order?

Comment: Ok, made the edit, I wasn't trying to stuff everything in one line but it just turned out that way... hope I've helped you with lots of stuff today :)

Comment: Thank you so much. You have a God-like knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the ranges like this:

```
timerange1 = {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.276504', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:39.286168'}
timerange2 = {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.482954', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:39.590220'}

# use a function to make this 'interval' data structure (instead of me being lazy)
interval1 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(timerange1['starting_time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")]
             datetime.datetime.strptime(timerange1['ending_time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")]
interval2 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(timerange2['starting_time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")]
             datetime.datetime.strptime(timerange2['ending_time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")]

def overlaps(interval1, interval2):
    results = []
    for timestamp in interval1:
        results.append(interval2[0] < timestamp < interval2[1])
    for timestamp in interval2:
        results.append(interval1[0] < timestamp < interval1[1])
    return True in results
```

Comment: is there a reason you are using list intermediate step?

Comment: To be complete in checking if any of the timestamps fall in between any of the intervals. the start/end times of interval1 might not be between interval2, but interval1 is "wider", so the start/end times of interval2 could fall in between interval1. Make sense?

Comment: no, I will make edit to your post showing how I would do it, you don't have to accept.

Comment: Cool, I'll add some more context to my answer to explain why I'm using the list.

Comment: ok I suggested it, I only really changed `for timestamp in interval1` to `for timestamp in interval1.values()` and `interval2[0]` to `interval2['starting_time']` and equivalent changes to use them as dictionaries instead of lists.

Comment: Ohh! I thought you meant the 'results' list on the 'overlaps' function, not me converting the askers dictionary to a list. I just did that while running it on my local machine to make the copy/paste easier. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 4mn, the following requires only 2mn number of comparisons for m records in Intervals1 and n records in Intervals2.

```
Intervals1 = [
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.276504', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:39.286168'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.722193', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.301116'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.329731', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:40.812676'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.146669', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.419473'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.413005', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.203540'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.686456', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.442964'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:43.198191', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.746994'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:44.502593', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:43.288611'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:46.525823', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:44.709627'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:47.098280', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:46.886541'}
    ]
Intervals2 = [
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.482954', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:39.590220'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:42.615738', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:41.649375'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:46.365902', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:45.987907'},
    {'ending_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:47.698375', 'starting_time': '2016-02-26 07:10:46.510641'}
    ]

for i1, d1 in enumerate(Intervals1):
  for i2, d2 in enumerate(Intervals2):
    start1 = d1["starting_time"]
    start2 = d2["starting_time"]
    end1 = d1["ending_time"]
    end2 = d2["ending_time"]

    if end1 >= start2 and end2 >= start1:
        print("Intervals1", i1, "overlaps with Intervals2", i2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice and short.
Took it from the colleagues, don't know the author )))

```
def is_overlapped(ranges):
    sorted_ranges = sorted(ranges, key=lambda begin_end: begin_end[0])
    return list(chain(*sorted_ranges)) != sorted(chain(*sorted_ranges))
```

##################################################################

Not overlapped:

> print(is_overlapped([
> (datetime(2023, 10, 1), datetime(2023, 12, 31)),
> (datetime(2020, 11, 1), datetime(2020, 12, 2))
> ]))

```
False
```

First in second:

> print(is_overlapped([ (datetime(2013, 10, 1), datetime(2013, 12, 31)),
> (datetime(2000, 11, 1), datetime(2020, 12, 2)) ]))

```
True
```

Second in first:

> print(is_overlapped([ (datetime(2013, 10, 1), datetime(2023, 12, 31)),
> (datetime(2020, 11, 1), datetime(2020, 12, 2)) ]))

```
True
```

First changing into second:

> print(is_overlapped([ (datetime(2010, 10, 1), datetime(2013, 12, 31)),
> (datetime(2013, 11, 1), datetime(2015, 12, 2)) ]))

```
True
```

Second changing into first:

> print(is_overlapped([ (datetime(2011, 10, 1), datetime(2013, 12, 31)),
> (datetime(2010, 11, 1), datetime(2011, 12, 2)) ]))

```
True
```

Comment: For anyone else: this worked - but requires `from itertools import chain` as well