# How can I clear a list of segments from nested segments (Python)

Tags: python, list, tuples, range, segment

My respect, colleagues.
I have a list of segments which may include nested segments that should be deleted.

For example we have a list (or maybe *other data structure*) of tuples:

```
[(50, 60), (10, 20), (10, 40), (40, 60), (60, 80), (75, 95), (95, 100)]
```

Or maybe list of ranges:

```
[range(50, 60), range(10, 20), range(10, 40), range(40, 60), range(60, 80), range(75, 95), range(95, 100)]
```

The result should be:

```
[(10, 40), (40, 60), (60, 80), (75, 95), (95, 100)]
```

[image]

And I must delete all nested segments.

In addition, I **am not allowed** to use any libraries or even `import`'s.

Actually, I'm confused, so I'll be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Why should `(50, 60), (10, 20)` be deleted? What is the logic for removing elements?

Comment: ok, say you have items `[(50, 60), (10, 20), (10, 100)]`, what should be the result?

Comment: @It_is_Chris The question, I think, is rhetorical . It's just a math problem should be solved using Python.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've wrote above (The result should be...)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest [(10, 100)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Removing overlapping lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312871/python-removing-overlapping-lists)

Answer (score 0):

For each segment, you check if it is nested in one the others segments. If it is, you use the `remove` function.

```
segments = [(10, 40), (40, 60), (60, 80), (75, 95), (95, 100)]

segments_copy = segments.copy()

for seg_1 in segments_copy:
    for seg_2 in segments_copy:
        if seg_1 != seg_2 and seg_1[0] >= seg_2[0] and seg_1[1] <= seg_2[1]:
            segments.remove(seg_1)
```