# Discarding isolated pairs of points

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a a list of a million pairs of integers `(a,b)`.  How can I prepare a data structure in python with the following property?   When I see a new pair of integers I would like to be able to tell if it overlaps any existing pair in my list very quickly?  Assuming `b > a` and `d > c` I say that (a,b) and (c,d) overlap if (`a <= c` and `b >= c`) or (`a<=d` and `b>=d`) or both a and b are between c and d.

Can this be done somehow in log time?

Comment: [Relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: This may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014242/python-dynamic-interval-data-structure

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the question. Assuming b > a and d > c, how can (a <= d and c >= d) be true? Is d > c true for all rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pre-process the existing data such that your data consists of non-overlapping intervals. That is if (a,b) and (c,d) intersect, you can merge them into a single interval (a,d) or (a,b) or (c,b) or (c,d) depending on the nature of the overlap.

More details on this step: Sort the intervals according to their start point (end point as secondary key). The merging step can be done at O(n) time then.

Now, sort the merged interval. For testing overlap, you can do two binary searches.

Comment: @Erhart I have added more info on the first step.