# Summing one array in terms of another - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, sum

I have two corresponding 2D arrays, one of velocity, one of intensity. The values of intensity match each of the velocity elements.

I have created another 1d array that that goes from min to max velocity in even bin widths.

How would I sum the intensity values from my 2d array which correspond to my velocity bins in my 1d array.

For example: if I have I = 5 corresponding to velocity = 101km/s, then this is added to the bin 100 - 105 km/s.

Here's my input:

```
rad = np.linspace(0, 3, 100) # polar coordinates
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

r, theta = np.meshgrid(rad, phi) # 2d arrays of r and theta coordinates

V0 = 225 # Velocity function w/ constants.
rpe = 0.149
alpha = 0.003

Vr = V0 * (1 - np.exp(-r / rpe)) * (1 + (alpha * np.abs(r) / rpe)) # returns 100x100 array of Velocities.

Vlos = Vr * np.cos(theta)# Line of sight velocity assuming the observer is in the plane of the polar disk.

a = (r**2) # intensity as a function of radius
b = (r**2 / 0.23)
I = (3.* np.exp(-1. * a)) - (1.8 * np.exp(-1. * b))
```

I wish to first create velocity bins from Vmin to Vmax and then sum the intensities over each bin.

My desired out put would be something along the lines of

```
V_bins = [0, 5, 10,... Vlos.max()]

I_sum = [1.4, 1.1, 1.8, ... 1.2]

plot(V_bins, I_sum)
```

EDIT: I have come up with temporary solution but perhaps there is a more elegant/efficient method of achieving it?

The two array Vlos and I are both 100 by 100 matrices.

```
Vlos = array([[ 0., 8.9, 17.44, ..., 238.5],...,
[-0., -8.9, -17.44, ..., -238.5]])

I = random.random((100, 100))



V = np.arange(Vlos.min(), Vlos.max()+5, 5)

bins = np.zeros(len(V))

for i in range(0, len(V)-1):
    for j in range(0, len(Vlos)): # horizontal coordinate in matrix
        for k in range(0, len(Vlos[0])): # vert coordinate

            if Vlos[j,k] >= V[i]and Vlos[j,k] < V[i+1]:
                bins[i] = bins[i] + I[j,k]
```

The result is plotted below.
The overall shape in the histogram is to be expected, however I don't understand the spike in the curve at V = 0. As far as I can tell this isn't there in the data which leads me to question my method.

[image: I don't expect the spike at zero and I would expect a smoother curve]

Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. What did you try? 2. Please show an example of what you are trying to do, otherwise it's hard to understand.

Comment: What you are looking for is an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014242/python-dynamic-interval-data-structure) for more information.

Comment: Please provide code that produces an example input and write the desired output as exact as you can.

Comment: I've added in some explanation of my code and the desired output, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
bins = np.arange(100,120,5)
velocities = np.array([101, 111, 102, 112])
intensities = np.array([1,2,3,4])
h = np.histogram(velocities, bins, weights=intensities)
print h
```

Output:

```
(array([4, 0, 6]), array([100, 105, 110, 115]))
```

Comment: I could use this method if I knew how to sum the intensities using the  corresponding velocities.
Is there a method (perhaps using indexing?) of summing elements of the intensity array with respect to the velocity array.

Comment: This is what histogram does. If you want something else, please show us a concrete example, with input and output numbers. Adding equations would make it more difficult for us.